# Gemfire Query interface - alternativies to gfsh/pulse

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Are there any thick-client alternatives to Pulse / Gfsh to query the regions of Gemfire? Though pulse is good, it's not usable as a sqldeveloper/toad for testing/querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none that I know of, sorry.

However, an alternative approach would be to use [Spring Data GemFire Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories) (additional details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.executing-queries)) to write/express your (OQL) queries, and then write automated [JUnit] tests to test your queries defined in your application `Repository` interface.

For [example](https://github.com/jxblum/actionable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/ContactRepository.java), I can define an interface extension of either the SDC's `[Crud]Repository` or SDG's `GemfireRepository` interface and declare [my application queries](https://github.com/jxblum/actionable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/ContactRepository.java#L27-L49) following certain [conventions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) (a specification of the query criteria defined by the interface method signature).  I.e. I do not need to write the actual queries.

Then, it is a relatively simple matter to define [tests](https://github.com/jxblum/actionable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/repository-example/src/test/java/example/app/repo/ContactRepositoryTests.java) to exercise your application's queries.

You can even express more [complex queries](https://github.com/jxblum/actionable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/CustomerRepository.java#L25-L28) (like Equi-Joins on 2 or more collocated PRs).  However, beware of the [query limitations involving PRs](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/query_additional/partitioned_region_query_restrictions.html#concept_5353476380D44CC1A7F586E5AE1CE7E8) in particular, as well as in [general](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/querying_basics/restrictions_and_unsupported_features.html).

More information on querying PRs can be found [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/querying_basics/querying_partitioned_regions.html), and specifically involving [Equi-Join Queries on PRs](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/partitioned_regions/join_query_partitioned_regions.html).

I have hard time imagining any tool successfully enabling this sort of practical querying since querying 2 collocated PRs (or a PR with any other Region type, e.g. `REPLICATE` or `LOCAL`) in an Equi-Join (OQL) Query must be performed inside a GemFire Function.

Anyway, I know this was not exactly what you were looking for since you probably just need something quick to test the validity of your query results in addition to analyzing the perf (like Explain Plan), but, this at least increases your test coverage in an automated, repeatable fashion.

Of course, this is all moot point if you are just looking to perform analysis on the data outside an application.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Agreed on the usage of SDG / Unit tests. But my question was more for test-teams usage for validation or querying some data. And additional features like Explain-plain would be really useful.

Comment: Yes, I figured so much.  +1 to having a feature similar to `explain plan`.  Sorry I could not help you more.